# Android view doesn't draw when applied a layout_below parameter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have this view i'm trying to implement, which is basically a thumb that is movable around a horizontal track.

It draws fine when it is in a RelativeLayout without any special layout parameters such as layout_below, but once i put a layout_below parameter on it, it doesn't draw at all!

What might be the cause of this?

public class TrackSlider extends View {

```
/**
 * The thumb of the slider will be limited to move so that it's center does
 * not go beyond the width of the track.
 */
public static final int THUMB_ANCHOR_CENTER = 0;

/**
 * The thumb of the slider will be limited to move so that it's edges do not
 * go beyond the width of the track.
 */
public static final int THUMB_ANCHOR_EDGES = 1;

private float mSliderPosition;
private float mSnapPosition = 0f;
private boolean mSnapEnabled = false;
private int mThumbAnchor;

private Drawable mThumbDrawable;
private Drawable mTrackDrawable;
private int mTrackWidth;
private int mSlideRange;
private int mThumbWidth;
private int mThumbXOffset;

public TrackSlider(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            styleable.TrackSlider);
    final int N = a.getIndexCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int attr = a.getIndex(i);
        switch (attr) {
        case styleable.TrackSlider_snapEnabled:
            setSnapEnabled(a.getBoolean(i, false));
            break;
        case styleable.TrackSlider_snapPosition:
            setSnapPosition(a.getFloat(i, 0.0f));
            break;
        case styleable.TrackSlider_startPosition:
            setThumbPosition(a.getFloat(i, 0.0f));
            break;
        case styleable.TrackSlider_thumb:
            setThumbDrawable(a.getDrawable(i));
            break;
        case styleable.TrackSlider_track:
            setTrackDrawable(a.getDrawable(i));
            break;
        case styleable.TrackSlider_thumbAnchor:
            mThumbAnchor = 0;//a.getInt(i, THUMB_ANCHOR_CENTER);
            break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int measuredWidth = 0, measuredHeight = 0;
    switch (MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec)) {
    case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
        measuredWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        break;
    case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        measuredWidth = Math.min(
                MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec),
                Math.max(mTrackDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                        mThumbDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth()));
        break;
    case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        measuredWidth = Math.max(mTrackDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                mThumbDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth());
        break;
    }
    switch (MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec)) {
    case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        measuredHeight = Math.min(MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec),
                Math.max(mTrackDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(),
                        mThumbDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight()));
        break;
    case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
        measuredHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        break;
    case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        measuredHeight = Math.max(mTrackDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(),
                mThumbDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        break;
    }
    setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right,
        int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    int w = right - left;
    if (mThumbAnchor == THUMB_ANCHOR_CENTER) {
        mTrackWidth = w - getPaddingRight() - getPaddingLeft()
                - mThumbWidth;
    } else {
        mTrackWidth = w - getPaddingRight() - getPaddingLeft();
    }
    mThumbXOffset = getPaddingLeft();
    mSlideRange = w - getPaddingRight() - getPaddingLeft()
            - mThumbWidth;
    mTrackDrawable.setBounds((w - mTrackWidth) / 2, top + getPaddingTop(), (w + mTrackWidth) / 2, getBottom() - getPaddingBottom());
    mThumbDrawable.setBounds(mThumbXOffset,
            getPaddingTop() + getTop(), mThumbXOffset + mThumbWidth,
            getBottom() - getPaddingBottom());
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    int pos = (int) (mSliderPosition * mSlideRange);
    Rect r = new Rect();
    mThumbDrawable.copyBounds(r);
    r.offset(pos, 0);
    mThumbDrawable.setBounds(r);
    mTrackDrawable.draw(canvas);
    mThumbDrawable.draw(canvas);
    r.offset(-pos, 0);
    mThumbDrawable.setBounds(r);
}

    /* getters and setters... */
```

}

layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:twoday="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com...."
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnContinue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/message"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_dialog_continue" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnContinue"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnContinue"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_dialog_cancel" />

    <com.twoday.gallerys.views.TrackSlider
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnCancel"
        twoday:snapEnabled="true"
        twoday:startPosition="0.5"
        twoday:thumb="@drawable/confirm_slider_thumb"
        twoday:thumbAnchor="center"
        twoday:track="@drawable/confirm_slider_track" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: are you certain that it is not being pushed off of the bottom of the screen?

Comment: The view is being drawn in a dialog, and the dialog doesn't take the entire screen, so it would be odd if it was pushed out, as i did set the layout_height attr to wrap_content...

Comment: Also, i can actually see room being made for it in the dialog (the dialog does get bigger as though the view was actually drawn but it isn't)

Comment: I don't know why it would be doing that. My best guess is try it without the custom attr's that you've created. Perhaps there is some bug that makes those cause the stock attr items not to work properly.

Comment: I tried removing the styled attributes but i get the same problem.

Comment: I don't see why it would change anything, but maybe try declaring the TrackSlider first with android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" then set all of the buttons to use android:layout_above="id". If layout_below specifically is the problem this might be a workaround.

Comment: What's really wierd is that when i debugged the onDraw method, it seemed to have the drawables' bounds actually set to the correct values, but still i see nothing in those bounds...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10203/discussion-between-tim-and-saarraz1)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a workaround for the problem - wrapping the view in a linearlayout then applying the layout_below attribute to the layout rather than the view itself.